# pcap filter selecting packets strictly incoming and outgoing a network

Tags: networking, libpcap

Let's say I am a router of a hub based local network `10.0.0.0/24` providing an access to internet.

```
+------+
| pc A +-----+
+------+     |
          +--+--+   +-------------+
          | hub +---+ router (me) +---- internet
          +--+--+   +-------------+
+------+     |
| pc B +-----+
+------+
```

I am implementing a small packet counter using libpcap to know the PPS of users in this network that goes from/to internet. For example, I want to **collect** packets:

- from A (or any internal, such as B) to stackoverflow.com (or any external)
- from stackoverflow.com to A (i.e. answers)

But I want to **filter** packets:

- from A to B (this is a hub based network so I see them)
- from A (or any internal) to me or the other way

The best filter I could do is `net 10.0.0.0/24 and \( not src net 10.0.0.0/24 or not dst net 10.0.0.0/24 \)` but isn't there a better syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simpler way to phrase your criteria would be "capture only ip packets between A and the router".

This can be expressed like this:

`ip and ether host AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA and ether host BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB` where `AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA` is the MAC address of A. and `BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB` is the router's MAC address.

Or `ip and not ether host CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC and ether host BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB` where `CC:CC:CC:CC:CC:CC` is your MAC. This would capture IP packets between the router and anyone on your network, except yourself.

Another option is `ip and host 1.2.3.4 and ether host BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB` where `1.2.3.4` is A's IP address.

There are many more possibilities.

Comment: Sorry the examples were unclear. Actually, I want to capture packets from *any* host in the network to an external host or the other way. For example, here I want to capture both A and B. I'll edit the question, it's unclear.

Comment: Your answer however gave me an idea. Something like `host \( ether $ROUTER_MAC and not ip $ROUTER_IP \)`. I am not sure this kind of syntax is allowed, and `ether host $ROUTER_MAC and not host ip $ROUTER_IP` is not the same request.